# ping machine in VM gives the wrong adapter ip

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine

I am studying Active directory. I created a virtual lab to experiment for the couse I am studying.
I am using Oracle VM 6.1 and I created 2 virtual machine. One where I installed Windows server 2019 and one wher eI installed Windows7 (my laptop cannot run anything bigger than that).
In each VM I created 2 network adapters, the first is attached to "internal network" on and the second to a "bridged adapter"
I then set the ip of the win2019 VM to 192.168.100.10 and the one for the Win7 machine to 192.168.100.50, both from the network configuration of the OSs.
I then activated the DNS service on the Win2019 and used 192.168.100.10 as DNS in the Win7 network configuration.
When I ping -4 server1 ( the anme I gave o the Win2019VM) from cmd in Windows7 I get as ip 192.168.100.31.
If I deactivate the bridged network adapters in both machines, I get the expected one, 192.168.100.10
If I reactivate the adapters, I get 192.168.100.31 again.
Seems WIN2019 gets the internal network adapter as second ethernet adapter.

From what I see on the course I am studing it is expected to have 192.168.100.10 as result of ping -4 server1 with both networks adapters active.

How can I get the DNS have server1 give 192.168.100.10 Ipv4  address when I ping it? Happy to provide more details if needed.
I am almost new to networking so please be patient if it is a stupid question. I checked the forum, but seems none posted this question here

Thnaks in advance

Edit this is the ipconfig /all for the Windows 2019 machine aka server1
[image: IP config win 2019]

This the win7 one
[image: Win 7 ipconfig part1]

[image: Win7 ipconfig part 2]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

IPCONFIG /ALL from both servers.

Comment: Hi Stas, thanks for answering me, I added the ipconfig /all screenshots in the original question.

Comment: I thing you have got ip address resolution  by NetBIOS. It sent broadcast request  by available adapter from Win7. And Win7 got response from server1 depended of with adapter was used. To best understand what happened you can install sniffer software like Wireshark. And try to catch DNS and NetBIOS packets.

Comment: You can look here, about ping and DNS resolution. https://serverfault.com/questions/312463/how-does-ping-work-when-a-host-name-has-multiple-ip-addresses